# In IIS Webserver, How to create a folder in the root directory to host download files?

Tags: iis, root, wordpress

I have Windows server 2012 r2 and an IIS webserver setup hosting 2 wordpress websites from the same dynamic ip address.

Everything is working great and as expected.

I am trying to figure out how to use one of my sites to host some  download files for a game server I also host.

The game calls for this structure mysitedotcom/tf/maps and I have placed the tf folder directly in the wwwroot folder and inside that is the maps folder with the map files within that.

Before when I rented my own server, It was an apache server and placing the tf/maps folders within the public_html folder allowed for a directory tree to come up when navigated to. This allowed for my members to download all of the map files by either clicking on them individually or using something like tortoise svn and grabbing them all at once.

How would I go about doing this in IIS? It is returning a 403 forbidden access error and I have seen this before when I installed the site. I had to change the sites default document to index.php because that is what wordpress used.

For the maps and tf folder I do not necessarily want it a part of my actual website mainly because my site has nothing to do with team fortress 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 403 is because you haven't configured the site to allow directory browsing. You can do so easily enough:

1. Make sure Directory Browsing is selected in the list of Roles and Features for IIS. (It is selected by default when you add the IIS role, so you probably have it.)
2. In IIS Manager, configure the site to allow directory browsing. Open the directory browsing feature for the site:

[image: Step 1]

Then enable the feature:

[image: Step 2]

Once you've enabled directory browsing, visiting the site without specifying a page name will show the directory listing:

[image]

Comment: Wow, you sir are a savior. Am I that terrible at using search engines because not once did I see anything about directory browsing! And I have been working at it all day sadly. I can see the folders now and the one test file I have within it but it will not let me download it and I believe that is because I need to add the correct extension for the file somewhere. It is a .bsp extension.

Comment: oops, so sorry I missed the last bit with the save target as. it works as expected. Wow, I can not thank you enough. Im new to superuser but will be back. My website is actually a tutorial site (just a hobby) with focus on creating thorough tutorials that explain with great detail the task at hand. I rate your little tutorial a 10/10 that you did for me and I may make my own with this very same issue. Thanks a lot!